# uk salary input regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

One question, I have a function for validate a number input. This input is used to introduce a salary in a uk website.
My problem is that I do not know how I have to change the regex to allow use the sign of pound sterling. Here is my function.

```
    form.isNumberValid = function(number)
    {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(\-)?([\d]+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$/);
        return pattern.test(number);  
    };
```

If someone can help me, I'll be very greatfull

Comment: `^(\-)?([\d]+(?:\.\d{1,2})?) ?£?$`

Comment: Why does your regex allow a `-` at the start of the number? People don't have salaries expressed as negative numbers.

Comment: @nicovank — The `£` symbol goes at the **front** of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another working way to do it in JS: `^(?:\d{1,3}\.)?(?:\d{3}\.)*\d{1,3}(?:, ?\d+)* ?(?:£|GBP)`.

It will make sure the number format is correct then check it is followed by `£` or `GBP` with or without space in between.

see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/0sBXFx/6

---

**[EDIT] after Quentin's comment.** Thank you.

so correct format should be: `£ ?(?:\d{1,3},)?(?:\d{3},)*\d{1,3}(?:\. ?\d+)*$`.

see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/0sBXFx/7

Comment: The `£` symbol goes at the **front** of the value, not the back.

Comment: British numbers use `.` to indicate the start of the decimal section, not a `,`

Comment: British numbers use commas when they separate numbers into group of 3, not `.` characters.

Comment: u are right, I googled the UK currency format and took the first which was wrong so let me update!